# How to convert PEM public key with -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- into openssl key starting with ssh-rsa

Tags: ssh, public-key

How to convert PEM public RSA key in the format:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

into openssl format:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAA...
```

Tried `openssl rsa -inform PEM -in id_rsa -pubout`  but gave the same PEM format. Read the man but not clear if openssl can convert it with which options.

```
$ openssl rsa -help
Usage: rsa [options]

General options:
 -help               Display this summary
 -check              Verify key consistency
 -*                  Any supported cipher
 -engine val         Use engine, possibly a hardware device

Input options:
 -in val             Input file
 -inform format      Input format (DER/PEM/P12/ENGINE
 -pubin              Expect a public key in input file
 -RSAPublicKey_in    Input is an RSAPublicKey
 -passin val         Input file pass phrase source

Output options:
 -out outfile        Output file
 -outform format     Output format, one of DER PEM PVK
 -pubout             Output a public key
 -RSAPublicKey_out   Output is an RSAPublicKey
 -passout val        Output file pass phrase source
 -noout              Don't print key out
 -text               Print the key in text
 -modulus            Print the RSA key modulus
 -traditional        Use traditional format for private keys

PVK options:
 -pvk-strong         Enable 'Strong' PVK encoding level (default)
 -pvk-weak           Enable 'Weak' PVK encoding level
 -pvk-none           Don't enforce PVK encoding

Provider options:
 -provider-path val  Provider load path (must be before 'provider' argument if required)
 -provider val       Provider to load (can be specified multiple times)
 -propquery val      Property query used when fetching algorithms
```

Comment: Better keywords could be OpenSSH and *authorized_keys*.

Comment: Crossdupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011572/convert-pem-key-to-ssh-rsa-format/ (but no longer ontopic there)

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, what you want is an Open**SSH** key, not an OpenSSL key, so you have to use SSH tools.

Try `ssh-keygen -ef id_rsa >out.tmp`

It will give you another base64 code between dashed lines, but it should be what you need. You then can remove the clutter with

`ssh-keygen -if out.tmp`

Comment: `ssh-keygen -e` only works if you have a privatekey or an _OpenSSH-format_ publickey, and OP here has neither. If you do have a privatekey you don't need the detour via 4716, just do `ssh-keygen -y`; and if you have OpenSSH publickey of course you needn't do anything. Instead try `ssh-keygen -i -m PKCS8` -- although the OP's format is actually X.509/PKIX SPKI and not PKCS8 at all, OpenSSH wrongly calls it PKCS8.